# How to Query Realm DB Browser?

Tags: realm

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1iXY.png][image: Realm DB]

I need to filter the DB on the basis of Id. On top there is search bar stating "Enter the query to filter the list". How to query to get some specific id filtered in RealmDB browser.

My DB URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1iXY.png

Comment: Have you tried using predicates?

Comment: Refer to the Realm-JS documentation for the predicate format accepted by Realm Studio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That field is used to enter queries aka [Filter](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries). Suppose you have a Dog Class with a dog_name property. To search for a Dog with the name Fido, you would enter this into the field

```
dog_name == "Fido"
```

The field is evaluated live so as soon as a valid query is entered, the results are updated.

If you look at the docs (this is Swift) you will see an example like this

```
// Query using a predicate string
var tanDogs = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("color = 'tan' AND name BEGINSWITH 'B'")
```

To apply the same filter, just use the part within the quotes in Realm Studio

```
color = 'tan' AND name BEGINSWITH 'B'
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this with "linked" ids? This only works for string compare on columns. If you are looking through Children for "parent.id = 123" it does not work when following the syntax in the linked docs.

Comment: @genkilabs It actually does work the same way with linked fields. For example, if you have a PersonClass with a property of dogs (a DogClass) which is a list, in the Realm Browser doing this `dogs.dog_name = "Dino"` query on the person class will return the Person whose dogs name is 'Dino'. If you are doing the opposite it will depend on how your Realm Objects are set up - do that have an inverse relationship? Perhaps posting a question with your Realm Object Models would be in order.